# Append input string to anchor tag href

Tags: javascript, anchor, href

Trying to append a string inputted by a user to an anchor tag href using vanilla js.

```
<script>
    function searchProduct(){
    var inputId = document.getElementById('inputId').value;
    document.getElementById('go').href = "mywebsite/product/" + inputId;
}
    searchProduct();
</script>


<a id="go"><p>Go</p></a>
```

However, this is not functioning

Comment: where do you trigger the function?

Comment: please show the html for the anchor tag

Comment: ok - and the input element too.

Comment: You're triggering `searchProduct()` on page load, before anyone has filled anything out in the `inputId` box.  You need to trigger that, on a button click, or onblur, or on something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're triggering `searchProduct()` once, when the page is loaded.  You need to trigger this after the input with the ID `inputId` is updated -- whether through a button press or when they leave the textbox, or something.

Here is an example which triggers the `searchProduct()` function when they leave the textbox:

```
(function() {
  function searchProduct(){
    var inputId = document.getElementById('inputId').value;
    document.getElementById('go').href = "mywebsite/product/" + inputId;
  }

  document.getElementById('inputId').addEventListener('blur', function() {
    searchProduct()
  });
})();
```

See [this jsBin](http://jsbin.com/qezubimawe/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: This is similar to what I was going to suggest. Very straight forward.

Comment: This is a good solution, the `addEventListener` function could pass `e.target.value` to the `searchProduct` function as an argument and the `getElementById('inputId').value;` could be avoided.

Comment: Not getting the desired result

Answer (score 0):

You should execute the function outside of itself, not inside

```
function searchProduct(){
    var inputId = document.getElementById('inputId').val();
    document.getElementById('go').href = "mywebsite/product/" + inputId;    
}

searchProduct(); // This should be executed via an eventListener to the input
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you want.

```js
  function searchProduct(){
    var inputValue = document.getElementById('inputId').value;
    document.getElementById('go').href =  "mywebsite/product/"+inputValue;
    }
```

```html
 <input id="inputId" type="text">
 <a id="go" onclick="searchProduct();" href="">anchor tag</a>
```

Comment: why is there a button if there is an a

Comment: Anchor tag is to open a link. And a button is to change the href of anchor tag.

Comment: no need for that step, remove the button from ur answer, put the onclick on anchor and i'll accept it. it works, thanks